# Redmine issue specific branch in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, git-branch, redmine

I have setup Redmine 3.3.2 and integrate it with GitlabCE 8.15.4.

I used '**Redmine GitLab Hook plugin**' for integration.

my question is "How to create issue specific branch in Gitlab from Redmine?"